# Perl JSON encode in UTF-8 strange behaviour

Tags: json, perl

Based on [Perl JSON 2.90](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm) documentation, to encode JSON object in UTF-8 all you need to do is:

> `$json_text = JSON->new->utf8->encode($perl_scalar)`

That is obvious and this what I did. After a while, I got an [issue report](https://github.com/qooob/authentic-theme/issues/282) on GitHub from one of users, which made me really surprised, as it shouldn't be happening!

I was beating for hours to figure out what was happening but the solution happened to be very weird and wrong from my point of view.

What eventually worked for me is this:

> `$json_text = JSON->new->latin1->encode($perl_scalar)`

After that, I tested this code with all different characters, including Russian and Chinese - it just worked?

Can anyone *please explain*, why encoding is working correctly with `latin1` and not with `utf8`, when it's actually has to be visa versa?

Comment: What do you actually do with your `$json_text` after encoding it? Do you have `use utf8` in your code and are you opening your filehandles specifying it? Because this looks a bit like a wide character that isn't being _decoded_ properly.

Comment: I have tried `use utf8;` in many different places. It didn't change a thing. I get JSON object using AJAX request.

Comment: I just do `print $json_text` and get this on the client-side.

Comment: That might be your problem - if whatever is _catching_ that print output isn't expecting UTF8.

Comment: It's inside of Webmin (It's my theme for Webmin). I tried many different ways. If you test the string (`JSON->new->utf8->encode($perl_scalar)`), it's not UTF-8. Doesn't `latin1` should break Russian and Chinese?

Comment: Going to need some example data/code/output I think before an answer can be given I think.

Comment: `use utf8` only affects your source code - it doesn't really do anything with respect to data. What really matters is how you put the data in `$perl_scalar` and how it gets into the client web page. I also would be looking at the `text-encoding` of the page and the AJAX response personally..

Comment: https://github.com/qooob/authentic-theme/blob/master/authentic-lib.cgi#L2720-L2751

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible bugs could result in the described outcome.

1. You were passing strings already encoded using UTF-8 to `encode`.

   If `$string` contains `installé` and `sprintf '%vX', $string` returns `69.6E.73.74.61.6C.6C.C3 A9`, are suffering from this bug.

   If you are suffering from the this bug, properly decode all inputs to your program, and continue using `JSON->new->utf8->encode` (aka `encode_json`).
2. You were encoding the output of the JSON command using UTF-8 a second time, possibly via a `:utf8` or `:encoding` layer on a file handle.

   If `$string` contains `installé` and `sprintf '%vX', $string` returns `69.6E.73.74.61.6C.6C.E9`, are suffering from this bug.

   If you are suffering from the this bug, either use `JSON->new->encode` (aka `to_json`) and keep the second layer of encoding, or use `JSON->new->utf8->encode` (aka `encode_json`) and remove the second layer of encoding.

In neither case is the solution to use `JSON->new->latin1->encode`.

Comment: That is true in theory but not in practice. This is why I stumbled here. From the docs: `latin1 - If $enable is true (or missing), then the encode method will encode the resulting JSON text as latin1 (or iso-8859-1), escaping any characters outside the code range 0..255.` -which turns to be no true. I just tested over again and _nothing_ works correctly. `to_json` just as when using `encode_json` (utf8) breaks the text.

Reading further says the folowing:
`If $enable is false, then the encode method will not escape Unicode characters unless required by the JSON syntax or other flags.`

Comment: `latin1` keeps things correct? https://github.com/qooob/authentic-theme/blob/master/authentic-lib.cgi#L2720-L2751.. That is just wrong.

Comment: `to_json` seems to encode as well? I think so, as I also get broken chars when using it.

Comment: I assure you everything I said is true. After a quick look at your code, I saw no decoding at all. So it appears your problem is the first one I mentioned. When you think you pass `é` to JSON, you are actually passing two other characters.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your explanation! I think, I still have misunderstanding about one ore few things. Let's say I have an associative array in PHP, all I do to output JSON object is `echo json_encode`. Are you saying that in Perl (I've just started with it really) I should decode it first? This is what makes no meaning to me? All I want to do is to get a hash (I think this is what associative array in Perl is), then turn it into JSON object and output this to the browser. Why are you mentioning decoding in this case scenario?

Comment: Re "*Are you saying that in Perl (I've just started with it really) I should decode it first?*", `->encode`, `encode_json` and `to_json` all expect input strings to be strings of decoded text (i.e. strings of Unicode Code Points). If you have strings of text encoded using UTF-8 (i.e. strings of bytes), then yes, you need to decode them first.

Comment: Thanks. Then is it more efficient to just use straight `->latin1-encode` or decode it first and then use `to_json` (_with utf8_)?

Comment: Efficiency only matters if you have two ways of doing it right. Again, this is covered by my answer. Why are you asking me to repeat it to you --twice!-- 2.5 years after I've posted it.

Comment: Thanks, in my case, I'd doubled up on utf8 when, of course, it was already baked into what I was up to.

Comment: @HughBarnard, Yeah, both the situation I mentioned are cases of double-encoding. The only difference in the two scenarios is whether the other instance of encoding happened before or after the JSON code.

Answer (score 3):

What are you doing to output `$json_text`? What kind of binmode do you use on that handle? The screenshot looks like it's double-encoded, which suggests the handle has `:utf8` or `:encoding` enabled (which is incorrect for writing encoded data to). As unintuitively as it may seem, `->latin1` giving a correct result matches that hypothesis (PerlIO assumes any binary string is encoded as latin-1).

Comment: .. and `latin1` doesn't encode already encoded data, as a result works correctly?

Comment: @Ilia Rostovtsev, `latin1` causes all instances of characters U+0100 and above to be encoded using JSON `\u` escapes, and encodes the remaining code points using iso-latin-1. This happens to work, but it's incorrect and wasteful.

Comment: @ikegami So in the end, how to make it work correctly and unwastefuly?

Comment: @ikegami I'm sorry if I make no sense. I just can't understand, do I have to keep using `->latin1->encode` to encode my existing data, because using exported function such as `encode_json` or `->utf8->encode` breaks its output.

Comment: Please refer to my answer. Your program had one of two possible bugs, and the fix depends on the bug from which the program suffers